# Mongodb backup or replication or clone with existing big data

Tags: mongodb

I have one mongo instance running on amazon. There are 5M docs in a single collection. And 20docs/1sec come in data. No index. And my server just have 50G space, already used 22G.

Now I need to do some data analyse for those data, but because on index, I execute one query, the db is block and can't insert data until I restart the server.

And data keep come in, so I worry about the space is not enough.

What I'm trying to do is build another server, setup a new mongo instance, then copy the data into it. Then add index on the new one and do the analyse.

Waht is the best way, any suggestion?

Comment: You want to just backup the mongodb data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way is to just create an index in the background. This will not block anything and you can then just run the indexed query on your node. Creating an index in the background takes a bit longer but it does prevent the blocking:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { col: 1 }, { background: true } );
```

See also: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/

If you really want a secondary to do analysis, then you can create a replica set from your existing member. But for that you will have to take MongoDB down - and restart it with the `replSet` parameter. After starting it with that parameter, you can now add a new replica set member which will sync the data. This synching will also impact performance as lots of data will have to be copied. The primary will also need more disk space now because of the `oplog` that MongoDB needs to sync secondaries with.

`mongodump` and `mongorestore` can also be an option but then the data between the two nodes will not stay in sync. You would have to run the dump+restore each time you want to run analysis on the new data. In that case, a replica set might be better.

A replica set really wants 3 members though, to prevent a split brain in case a node goes down. This can be another data node, but in your case you would probably want to set-up an arbiter. If you *don't* want automatic failover (I don't think you'd need it in this case, as you're just doing analysis), then set up your replica set two nodes, but make the second (new) one hidden: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-a-hidden-replica-set-member/

Comment: Hi @Derick, thanks a lot. It's do solve my issue. And also make me get more understand for mongo.

Answer (score 0):

1. set up replica set from this existing member, and then add the index
   on the secondary and do analysis.
2. Take a mongodump and restore to a new server and do the analysis